# Audible iTunes Linux

Tags: linux, ipod

Using Linux Mint I need to find some way of running iTunes so i can update my 7th Gen iPod, which cannot be done in `Rhythmbox`.

I've tried legacy versions of iTunes in WINE.
I've tried to use play on Linux.
I've not tried to run Windows in VirtualBox yet.

Has anyone previously done this, or have any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe virtualbox + USB redirect/passthrough should be the best way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I was ever able to get this to work was to run Windows in a VM. There used to be directions floating around on the internet for running iTunes under Wine, but I had a lot of problems with that route, and ended up going the VirtualBox using Windows route.

In case you've never setup VirtualBox with a VM with Windows there are pretty good instructions on the general steps here on the Ubuntu Official documents page, titled: [PortableDevices/iPhone/iTunesVirtualBox](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PortableDevices/iPhone/iTunesVirtualBox).